# Android, is there an OnRelease functions?

Tags: java, android

Say I want a dialog to `.show()` when the user Touches a certain element and `.hide()` once he releases it.

I found how to make the `OnTouchListener`. But is there any sort of `OnReleaseListener`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats actually included in the `OnTouchListener`. It gives you a MotionEvent on the callback,
use `MotionEvent.getAction()` and check if it equals `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. That means the user released the finger.

Equally you can check for `ACTION_DOWN` to differentiate the two.

Answer (score 2):

`onTouchListener` returns you a `TouchEvent` object, which contains the current touch action, that can be retrieved by calling `event.getAction()`. There are some actions, one of them are `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`: first tells you, that the user has touched some view, and second tells you that user has taken his finger off a view. Means `onRelease` will be `onTouch` with the `ACTION_UP` action. Hope this helps.